# React Router - handle 403 response from server and render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, koa

In my app I'm using `connected-react-router` as follows:

```
render() { 

// .... some code

   return 
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
               <Route 
                   path="/sample/route"
                   component={SampleComponent}
               />
               <Route 
                   path="/another/sample/route"
                   component={AnotherSampleComponent}
               />
               <Route 
                   component={NotFoundComponent}
               />
            </Switch>
       </ConnectedRouter>
```

This works fine for rendering the `NotFound` component for any routes which don't exist.

However, when a user tries to access `/sample/route` in their browser, my app's server carries out some auth checks in order to check if the user is authorised to access this route.

If not, the server returns a `403` as follows:

```
   ctx.status=403
   ctx.body="Unauthorised"
   return ctx
```

I would like to intercept this `403` response code and display a component which I have defined in my client-side React code, similar to the `NotFoundComponent`. At the moment, the user sees a white page with `Unauthorised` written on it. Is there a way I can do this? I would like to avoid copy-pasting the component onto my server and returning it from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to intercept server side handling of a route when opened directly *(but clicks can*)*. Instead of copy and pasting your code you could have your server return your react app on 403s just like it does on all other routes. Then you can add a corresponding react route and render a login form for example.
To avoid collisions app routes are often put under a sub route like `/myapp/`, `/api/` or a completely different (sub) domain.

** When you define a corresponding route and use a `<Link>` tag instead of an `<a>` a click will be intercepted.*

Comment: Could you provide a brief code example of how the server and router would be altered? I'm a bit confused by the answer